# Unexpected results using strptime in R

Tags: r, datetime, strptime

Last year, I used the code below to convert the character string to a datetime and it worked, but now I get unexpected results after running `strptime`.

```
Data <- structure(list(time = c("12:00 AM", "1:00 AM", "2:00 AM",
  "3:00 AM", "4:00 AM", "5:00 AM", "6:00 AM", "7:00 AM", "8:00 AM",
  "9:00 AM", "10:00 AM", "11:00 AM")),
  .Names = "time", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Why does this give me the expected results from strptime:

```
strptime(Data$time[1:10], format="%l:%M %p")
#  [1] "2013-03-01 00:00:00" "2013-03-01 01:00:00" "2013-03-01 02:00:00"
#  [4] "2013-03-01 03:00:00" "2013-03-01 04:00:00" "2013-03-01 05:00:00"
#  [7] "2013-03-01 06:00:00" "2013-03-01 07:00:00" "2013-03-01 08:00:00"
# [10] "2013-03-01 09:00:00"
```

But when I try to replace the existing data with the new data format, I get a warning and the unexpected results below:

```
Data$time[1:10] <- strptime(Data$time[1:10], format="%l:%M %p")
# Warning message:
# In Data$time[1:10] <- strptime(Data$time[1:10], format = "%l:%M %p") :
#   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
Data
#                                                time
# 1                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
# 2                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
# 3                      0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
# 4                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
# 5                      2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
# 6  113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113
# 7                      5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
# 8            59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59
# 9                      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
# 10                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
# 11                                         10:00 AM
# 12                                         11:00 AM
```

---

When I run the code `Data$time[1:10] <- strptime(Data$time[1:10], format="%l:%M %p")` in the question above and `View(Data)` the resulting data in the standard RGui it looks as expected, however when I `View(Data)` in RStudio the unexpected results above are displayed.  In both RGui and RStudio the function `class(Data$time)`, returns `[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"` and behaves as expected.  This appears to be a problem with displaying the data in RStudio.

Comment: Is it normal that you have negative times?

Comment: Also, shouldn't your "format" argument match the structure of the input?

Comment: And *what* is the format of your input?

Comment: They format correctly in line 1 to the correct times...  The format is originally numeric.

Comment: the times are all preceded by the date 1900-01-01 but R uses 1970-01-01 as 1 so these are negative

Comment: for more on the way that I am using the format function see http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html @AnandaMahto

Comment: @cwhit25 just looking at your first line - `1244174400  -2209143600` - what are your expected results?  :)

Comment: @AnthonyDamico The expected results for DateTime for the first observation is 2009-06-05 00:00:00.  Oh and a side note the times have 1899-12-30 originally appended.

Comment: Ok, and how do you go from 1244174400 -2209143600 to 2009-06-05 00:00:00?

Comment: @AnandaMahto does the information about the expected results above help?

Comment: @cwhit25 could you explain, step by step, exactly how the input number is _supposed_ to be converted to `2009-06-05 00:00:00`?  don't worry about code, just explain it in words :)

Comment: @AnthonyDamico so line 1: removes the 1899-12-30 so that Time is just the time; line 2: concatenates the two strings from DATE and TIME into one field; line 3: converts this to datetime format.  strptime seems to be working correctly as shown in the edit above.  the problem seems to happen when assigning it to the variable.

Comment: @cwhit25 but please don't tell us what your broken code is supposed to do.  just tell us what tasks a human would perform to convert your given input to your desired output.  :)

Comment: I updated the question to reflect more of what I am really trying to ask.  Please focus on the update at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Your update does not help without sample data.  There is no way for anyone to [reproduce your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616), which makes it incredibly hard to help you.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich  I added the data for the updated question

Comment: Upon further inspection, this appears to be a bug with the display of the data in the RStudio GUI that I am using...

Comment: WOW. This question has changed *a lot* since its first edit. @cwhit25, with that last comment, are you trying to say your problem is solved?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this would have worked in the past, unless it was supported in an earlier version of R...

`strptime` returns a `POSIXlt` object, which is a list with several components (see `?POSIXlt` for a description of the elements).  The problem arises because you try to replace a portion of a character vector with a `POSIXlt` object.  This converts the entire column into a list, where the first 10 elements are the components of the `POSIXlt` object, and the last two are the original elements from the character vector.

Everything will work fine if you replace the *entire* column with the result from `strptime` or make a new column with the result from `strptime`:

```
Data$time2 <- strptime(Data$time, format="%l:%M %p")
Data$time  <- strptime(Data$time, format="%l:%M %p")
```

Comment: The code in the question above does work and I was only shortening it to the first few  rows because I have a 130,000+ observations and didn't think that would be appropriate to include in the question.

Comment: @cwhit25: you don't have to include _all_ your data to make a reproducible example.  You could find a subset of the data that illustrates the issue.

Comment: The point is the data displays in RStudio in the wrong format whether using a portion of or the ENTIRE column even though it responds, behaves, and prints correctly in the console.  It only looks unusual when using View() in RStudio.  In RGui, View() displays the correct datetime.

Comment: @cwhit25: then file a bug report with RStudio...

Comment: Right... I just feel that the question and answer are now kind of misleading.  I tried to answer it but it got deleted.  Sorry this is the first time I have used SO and obviously have a lot to learn about how all this works.